# ¿Como usar contenido de un archivo .js en un index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

No se si estoy claro con la pregunta, pero tampoco se bien como expresar mi situacion, estoy practicando en el tema de javascript, tengo un index.html y por otro lado un archivo de extension javascript, como debo hacer para pasar datos que tengo en el .js hacia el index.html?
Quiero pasarlos y poder desplegarlos mediante texto simple en la pantalla mediante html, todo muy sencillo.

Perdon los inconvenientes, la idea es tomar los resultados de fichas funciones y expresarlos en un texto en el navegador con el html.
El codigo es muy sencillo dado que recien empiezo a utilizar estas herramientas.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>PRUEBA</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
      var num1=20;
var num2=2;
var result=num1+num2;

function suma (val1, val2) {
    val1=num1;
    val2=num2;
    result=val1+val2;
}
function resta (val1, val2) {
    val1=num1;
    val2=num2;
    result=val1-val2;
}
function multiplicacion (val1, val2) {
    val1=num1;
    val2=num2;
    result=val1*val2;
}
function division (val1, val2) {
    val1=num1;
    val2=num2;
    result=val1/val2;
}

suma();
console.log("Suma: " + result);
console.log("\n");
resta();
console.log("Resta: " + result);
console.log("\n");
multiplicacion();
console.log("Multiplicacion: " + result);
console.log("\n");
division();
console.log("Division: " + result);
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega tu código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder al DOM desde app.js con la propiedad document.getElementById('id') e insertas el texto con innerHTML = 'TEXTO'

```js
var num1 = 20;
var num2 = 2;
var result = num1 + num2;

function suma(val1, val2) {
  val1 = num1;
  val2 = num2;
  result = val1 + val2;
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = 'Suma: ' + result;
}

function resta(val1, val2) {
  val1 = num1;
  val2 = num2;
  result = val1 - val2;
  document.getElementById("resta").innerHTML = 'Resta: ' + result;
}

function multiplicacion(val1, val2) {
  val1 = num1;
  val2 = num2;
  result = val1 * val2;
  document.getElementById("multiplicacion").innerHTML = 'Multiplicacion: ' + result;
}

function division(val1, val2) {
  val1 = num1;
  val2 = num2;
  result = val1 / val2;
  document.getElementById("division").innerHTML = 'Division: ' + result;
}

suma();
resta();
multiplicacion();
division();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Prueba</h1>
  <p id="suma"></p>
  <p id="resta"></p>
  <p id="multiplicacion"></p>
  <p id="division"></p>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probé tu código y anduvo a la perfección, lo uní con algo mas que se me ocurrió y quedo genial, gracias.

Comment: @FabricioBarrios de nada.

Answer (score 0):

Te diré que debes poner una etiqueta script en tu fichero HTML que apunte a tu fichero Javascript y ya estarás en situación de usar tu Javascript en tu pagina HTML. Seria algo así:

```
 <script src="ruta/a/tu/fichero.js"></script>
```

Mira....así lo haría yo si fuese tu:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<body>
 <h1>PRUEBA</h1>
 <p id="suma"></p>
    <p id="resta"></p>
    <p id="multi"></p>
    <p id="division"></p>
    <script>
  function suma (val1, val2) {
       return val1+val2;
  }
  function resta (val1, val2) {
            return val1-val2;
  }
  function multiplicacion (val1, val2) {
            return val1*val2;
  }
  function division (val1, val2) {
            return val1/val2;
  }
  document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = "La suma es " + suma(3,9);
        document.getElementById("resta").innerHTML = "La resta es " + resta(3,9);
        document.getElementById("multi").innerHTML = "La multiplicacion es " + multiplicacion(3,9);
        document.getElementById("division").innerHTML = "La division es " + division(9,3);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahi agregue informacion

Comment: Perdon por el lapsus, así mejor????

Comment: y si quisiera por ejemplo traer el valor de la variable result a mi index y desplegarlo en un texto <p> </p>. perdon por la molestia

Comment: Eso sería otra pregunta....nooooo???? No se si puedes repreguntar dentro de esta misma otra pregunta o tienes que lanzar una pregunta nueva. Leete las normas, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar esto al final tu html(index.html)

```
<script src="/path/to/file/tuarchivo.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo lo que queres hacer es lo siguiente

Agregar 1 div por cada operación

```
<div id='suma'></div>
```

Agregar un return del calculo en cada función

```
function suma (val1, val2) {
    val1=num1;
    val2=num2;
    result=val1+val2;
    return result;
}
```

Luego de cada llamada de función agregar

```
resu = suma();
resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
resultado.innerHTML = resu
```